# Basic Logic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Easy one that I can't figure out: I have a blog app with an `Article` model. On my `welcome#index` page, I would like to display each of the titles of the last four articles that have been posted.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

def index
    @articles = Article.all
end
end
```

In my view, I need each of the titles to be displayed separately in its corresponding html 'box'. For the first title I wrote the following code:

```
%title #{ @articles.last(1).title }
```

For which I get an `undefined method 'title'` error.

Any idea as to why that happens?

Comment: Use @articles = Article.last(4) to get last 4 post, then Iterate to all of them to get title.

Comment: Okay, that's great. How do I iterate each of the titles separately?

Comment: @liroy Just use `.each` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@articles.last(1)` give the last article inside an `Array` like:

```
[ #<Artile id: ..> ]
```

So you need to do like `@articles.last(1).first.title`.

If you are really interested to the last article, you can do simple like :

```
@articles.last.title
```

Because `@articles.last` gives you the article object directly :

```
#<Article id: ..>
```

To iterate, you will use `.each` like :

```
- @articles.each do |article|
    %title #{ article.title }
```

populate the `@articles` in your controller like :

```
@articles = Article.order('updated_at asc').last(4)
```

Comment: The each loop multiplies my html elements by four! Why does that happen?

Comment: @liroy show your HTML code in a separate question.. we will help you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Imran and Arup answer, if you really just need title column you can just query it like this `@articles = Article.last(4).pluck(:title)`

Answer (score 1):

I think should your code

```
@articles = Article.order('updated_at asc').last(4) # Controller
```

View

```
<% @articles.each do |title| %>
  <%= title.title %> #-> print last 4 title
<% end %>
```

Hope will help you